# Spring transaction management over a datasource list

Tags: java, spring, spring-transactions, transactional

I have a Spring mvc rest webservice with a `DataSourceManager` bean that holds a map of datasource. Every customer has his own database and therefore his own datasource. The webservice loads the customer Datasource programmatically loading from `DataSourceManager` and if it does not exist it creates a new.

With this implementation is possible to use an annotation driven transaction management ? All the examples that I read have one or various datasources declared all on a config file.

Comment: What you basically have is multi tenancy, when setup correctly you can use normal transactional demarcation as if you have a single datasource. One such thing is documented [here](https://mdeinum.wordpress.com/2007/01/05/one-application-per-client-database/). We used it for a web application but it shouldn't be that hard to apply it to a web service (basically a web application as well).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved my problem with this bean:

```
@Bean
@Scope(value=WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public PlatformTransactionManager txManager(SessionInfo sessionInfo, DataSourceManager dsManager)   
{               
    return dsManager.getTransactionManager(sessionInfo.getCustomerId()); 
}
```

Where `SessionInfo` is a session bean that holds the customer and `DataSourceManager` is a global bean that holds all the Datasources. Every web request load the correct Transaction Manager and the `@Transactional` annotation works with the corresponding datasource.
It seems that works